# How to show that $\{x\in \mathbb Z: p-1<x<p+2n+1\}=\{p,p+1,…,p+2n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

> How to show that $\{x\in \mathbb Z: p-1<x<p+2n+1\}=\{p,p+1,…,p+2n\}$

It's quite trivial from the experiance but is there any concrete mathematical result to justify it?

I think all we need to show is that there is no integer other than $p,p+1,…,p+2n$ satisfying $p-1<x<p+2n+1.$

Comment: This really falls under the category of set theory.  The usual way you would prove the equality of two sets is to show containment in both directions.  That is $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$ implies that $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

The basic result needed is that
if $n$ and $m$ are integers
and $n > m$
then $n \ge m+1$
(and, similarly,
if $n < m$ then
$n \le m-1$).

Oddly,
I'm not really sure if this is trivial
or subtle.
I guess it would depend on the
syetem you are working in.

Getting this in the Peano system
would be quite different than
getting this in standard number theory.

I'll leave it at that for the experts.